# Run multiple models of an ensemble in parallel with PyTorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, ensemble-learning

My neural network has the following architecture:

```
input -> 128x (separate fully connected layers) -> output averaging
```

I am using a ModuleList to hold the list of fully connected layers. Here's how it looks at this point:

```
class MultiHead(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, dim_state, dim_action, hidden_size=32, nb_heads=1):
        super(MultiHead, self).__init__()

        self.networks = nn.ModuleList()
        for _ in range(nb_heads):
            network = nn.Sequential(
                nn.Linear(dim_state, hidden_size),
                nn.Tanh(),
                nn.Linear(hidden_size, dim_action)
            )
            self.networks.append(network)

        self.cuda()
        self.optimizer = optim.Adam(self.parameters())
```

Then, when I need to calculate the output, I use a `for ... in` construct to perform the forward and backward pass through all the layers:

```
q_values = torch.cat([net(observations) for net in self.networks])

# skipped code which ultimately computes the loss I need

self.optimizer.zero_grad()
loss.backward()
self.optimizer.step()
```

**This works!** But I am wondering if I couldn't do this more efficiently. I feel like by doing a `for...in`, I am actually going through each separate FC layer one by one, while I'd expect this operation could be done in parallel.

Answer (score 10):

In the case of `Convnd` in place of `Linear` you could use the `groups` argument for "grouped convolutions" (a.k.a. "depthwise convolutions"). This let's you handle all parallel networks simultaneously.

If you use a convolution kernel of size `1`, then the convolution does nothing else than applying a `Linear` layer, where each *channel* is considered an input dimension. So the rough structure of your network would look like this:

1. Modify the input tensor of shape `B x dim_state` as follows: add an additional dimension and replicate by `nb_state`-times  `B x dim_state` to `B x (dim_state * nb_heads) x 1`
2. replace the two `Linear` with

```
nn.Conv1d(in_channels=dim_state * nb_heads, out_channels=hidden_size * nb_heads, kernel_size=1, groups=nb_heads)
```

and

```
nn.Conv1d(in_channels=hidden_size * nb_heads, out_channels=dim_action * nb_heads, kernel_size=1, groups=nb_heads)
```

4. we now have a tensor of size `B x (dim_action x nb_heads) x 1` you can now modify it to whatever shape you want (e.g. `B x nb_heads x dim_action`)

---

While CUDA natively supports grouped convolutions, there were some issues in pytorch with the speed of grouped convolutions (see e.g. [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/22302)) but I think that was solved now.

Comment: Sounds promising, will try it out! I think your first code snippet suffered from a copy-paste error though ;-)

Comment: Huh, I don't know how that got in there, sorry!